# calculate expected cost of final product using atleast k out of n items in c

Tags: c, algorithm

Suppose I have 4 items and i have to pick at least 1 item to make a product out of them.
I have cost corresponding to each item as Item1 -> 4 , Item2 -> 7 , Item3 -> 2 , Item4 -> 5.I have to to find expected cost of the final product means an average of all possible combinations Item used like if I use only 1 item then cost may be 4 , 7 , 2 ,  5 and if if i use 2 items the cost would be 4+7 , 4+2 , 4+5 , 7+2 , 7+5 , 2+5 and similarly all combinations for using three items and 4+2+7+5 for using four items.Adding those all combinations and dividng them with no. of combination gives me expected cost of the final product.So I want to find sum of all these combinations then how can I go for it??

I think recursion will be used for calculating these combination but unable to apply ???

Comment: I've been thinking about this kind of algorithim too. But can you be specific which language are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using recursion to generate all the possible subsets, you can use bit manipulation. For the example given with 4 items, there are 2^4 possible subsets. So you can represent these 2^4 subsets using a 4 digit binary number. The binary numbers will count from 0 to 2^4-1=15. And for each number, you check the state of the 4 bits. If the bit is set then that element is included in that subset, otherwise it is not.

You can easily implement this logic in the form of a [Working Java Program](http://ideone.com/RvieFt).

```
        int[] arr = {4 , 7 , 2 , 5};
        double ans = 0;
        int numCombinations = (int)Math.pow(2, arr.length);

        // Iterate over all the subsets represented in the form of binary numbers
        for(int i=0; i<numCombinations; i++){
            int sum = 0;

            // check whether a bit is set or not. If the bit is set, then that 
            // number is present in that subset, else it is not present.
            for(int bit=0; bit<arr.length; bit++){
                if( (i & (1<<bit)) != 0){
                    sum += arr[bit];
                }
            }
            ans += (double)sum;
        }

        //Divide by numCombinations-1 as we are not considering the empty subset{}
        System.out.println(ans/(numCombinations-1));
```

This program correctly calculates the answer as 9.6 for the given case.

Running Time `O(n.2^n)`

Edit: **A better solution**

Suppose you are generating all subsets of n elements. Now there are two possibilities for the n the element. It will either be included or it will be not included. So suppose you have all the n-1 element subsets. For all these n-1 element subsets, you will do one of the above mentioned two cases, ie. you will include the nth element or not. Thus, we can say that **if we have a total of M subsets, then any element will be present M/2 times**.

In the given case M is 2^n as we are generating all the subsets. So any element will be present 2^(n-1) times.

So the total sum of all the numbers in all the subsets will be

> Sum of numbers of all subsets = arr[0] * 2^(n-1) + arr[1](http://ideone.com/RvieFt) * 2^(n-1) + .......arr[n] * 2^(n-1)

dividing this by the number of subsets will give the answer.

> Total number of subsets = 2^n - 1.

We are subtracting 1 as we are not considering the empty subset {}.

So for the given case, answer will become
(4+7+2+5) * 2^(n-1)  / (2^n - 1)  =  9.6

Running Time: `O(n)`

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of symmetry in this problem which means you don't need a program to solve it.

(1) There are 4 possible "products" with 1 part
(2) There are 6 (4*3/2) products with 2 parts
(3) There are 4 (4*3*2/(3*2*1) products with 3 parts
(4) There is one product with 4 parts.

Total number of combinations = 15 (I assume we can ignore the "one product with zero parts").

Now in each case, every item is used the same fractional number of times:

for (1), you use each 1/4 of the time
for (2), you use each 1/2 of the time
for (3), you use each 3/4 of the time
for (4), you use them all the time.

So each part is used in a total of 1 + 3 + 3 + 1 = 8 out of 15 configurations.

Thus the "expected cost" is

```
(8/15) * (4+7+2+5) = 18 * 8 / 15 = 9.6
```

**edit** how could you have come up with the number `8/15` without explicitly counting? Well, you could note that you can think of the possible combinations (part is used or part is not used) as a binary number with four digits (since there are four parts) - this has been pointed out in other answers. When you list all binary numbers from `0b0000` to `0b1111` you know every position will have the same number of ones and zeros - 8 of each. Leaving out `0b0000` which is "not a product", you find yourself still with 8 ones for each product - thus 8 out of 15.

Answer (score 0):

If you represent the use of an item as a set bit in an integer then you can simply iterate from 1 to 15 and use bit manipulation to determine the cost.
In (pseudo) C

```
cost = 0.0;
for(i=1;i<=15;++i)
{
  for(j=0;j<4;++j)
  {
    if(i & (1<<j)) cost += item_cost[j];
  }
}
average = cost / 15.0;
```

**Edit**:

Assuming that you want to put a bound of `k` on the fewest number of items

```
n = 0;
cost = 0.0;
for(i=1;i<=15;++i)
{
  sum = 0.0;
  used = 0;
  for(j=0;j<4;++j)
  {
    if(i & (1<<j))
    {
     sum += item_cost[j];
     ++used;
    }
  }

  if(used>=k)
  {
    cost += sum;
    ++n;
  }
}
average = cost / n;
```

Comment: But the result will be `(8./15.)*sum(item_cost)`, so it could be computed more efficiently :) (Because in the 15 combinations, every item is selected exactly 8 times).

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to distinguish your items from each other, and the set of combinations is entirely symmetric, so in the set of all possible combinations, every item is selected the same number of times as every other item.

So we can simplify the problem by replacing every item's cost with the average item cost, and then just count the number of items selected in all combinations and the total number of combinations. That makes the average cost of a combination:

```
average item cost * total number of items
-----------------------------------------
      total number of combinations
```

In the case where `k = 1`, the total number of combinations is `2n-1` and the total number of items in all the combinations is `n×2n-1`.

Comment: Can we assume that items can be duplicated?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be solved mathematically-

Let 'n' be total no. of elements & 'k' be no. of items to be consider for combinations.

SUM = sum of all elements in array

COMBINATIONS = k items selected from n i.e., (n C k)

FREQUENCY = frequency of each item in all combinations i.e., (n-1 C k-1)

So the solution is-
Ans = SUM * FREQUENCY / COMBINATIONS

After simplification-
Ans = SUM * k / n

```
package com.kvvssut.misc;

public class AverageOfCombinations {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getAverageOfAllKCombinations(new int[]{4,7,2,5,8}, 3));
    }

    private static double getAverageOfAllKCombinations(int[] inputs, int k) {

        int n = inputs.length;
        long sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            sum += inputs[i];
        }

        double output = 0;
        if (k >= n) {
            output = sum;
        } else if (k > 0) {
            double combinations = 1;
            double divider = 1;

            for (int i = n; i > k; i--) {
                combinations *= i;
            }
            for (int i = 2; i <= k; i++) {
                divider *= i;
            }
            combinations /= divider;

            double frequency = 1;
            for (int i = n - 1; i > k; i--) {
                frequency *= i;
            }
            divider = 1;
            for (int i = 2; i < k; i++) {
                divider *= i;
            }
            frequency /= divider;

            output = sum * frequency / combinations;
        }
        return output;
    }

}
```

Plz correct me if wrong.